# Strange messages?

Tags: macos, messages

Im hoping some friendly soul would have the time to review these system messages im getting. Are they normal?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you having a particular issue that caused you to look into console messages for notifications?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they are normal.

Don't be alarmed by the fact that it is mentioning destroying databases, etc. This is normal output from apsd.